# python script launch with cron fails when parsing XML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, raspberry-pi3, cron-task

I try to do domotic on 2 different devices with python script on my raspberry py.The script runs several tasks:

1. Launch external command to get some informations on  serial port on device 1
2. get string as a response
3. parse result to build a dictionary
4. Launch external command to get get informations by *mbus* on device 2
5. get XML string as a response
6. parse this string
7. add couple of informations to initial dictionary
8. send the dictionary as a post JSON request over to a web server

If I launch the script manually, everything go fine.

If I launch the script with cron, script get freeze on parsing XML string come from device 2.

- I launch the script with absolute path : `python /home/<user>/script/dom.py`
- If I remove device 2 parsing (step 6 & 7), cron runs fine
- I have tried to parse string with DOM and SAX way, same freeze at parsing stage
- XML string is about 80 lines long.

Is XML parsing process too slow ? How can I work this around?
I really wants to avoid writing to a file, since rewriting is no good for the SD card...
Thanks

here is the function freezing:

```
nv = {}
id =''
def pw3_parseDOM( XMLstr):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(XMLstr))
    root = tree.getroot()
    root.tag
    root.attrib

    for child in root:
        if (child.tag == CONST_XML_DATARECORD):
            Val = ''
            Nam = ''
            for value in child:
                if value.tag == CONST_XML_VALUE:
                    Val = value.text
                elif value.tag == CONST_XML_UNIT:
                    Nam = Shortcut.get(value.text, 'None')                        
            if(Nam == 'pw3_temp_in' or Nam == 'pw3_temp_out'):
                nv[Nam] = str(Val).decode('utf-8')
            elif(Nam == 'pw3_temp_delta'):
                nv[Nam] = str(Val).decode('utf-8')
        elif (child.tag == CONST_XML_INFO):
            for c in child:
               if(c.tag == CONST_XML_ID):
                   id = c.text
```

and a typical xml string passed to pw3_parseDOM():

```
<MBusData>
<SlaveInformation>
    <Id>13745998</Id>
    <Manufacturer>ITR</Manufacturer>
    <Version>24</Version>
    <ProductName></ProductName>
    <Medium>Heat: Outlet</Medium>
    <AccessNumber>39</AccessNumber>
    <Status>00</Status>
    <Signature>0000</Signature>
</SlaveInformation>
<DataRecord id="0">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Fabrication number</Unit>
    <Value>13745998</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="1">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Energy (kWh)</Unit>
    <Value>29052</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="2">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Volume (1e-2  m^3)</Unit>
    <Value>349893</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="3">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Power (100 W)</Unit>
    <Value>0</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="4">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Volume flow (m m^3/h)</Unit>
    <Value>0</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="5">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Flow temperature (1e-1 deg C)</Unit>
    <Value>260</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="6">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Return temperature (1e-1 deg C)</Unit>
    <Value>235</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="7">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Temperature Difference (1e-2  deg C)</Unit>
    <Value>256</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="8">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Time Point (time &amp; date)</Unit>
    <Value>2018-02-02T22:48:00</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="9">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Operating time (days)</Unit>
    <Value>1647</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="10">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Firmware version</Unit>
    <Value>7</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="11">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Software version</Unit>
    <Value>8</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="12">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Volume (1e-1  m^3)</Unit>
    <Value>0</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="13">
    <Function>Instantaneous value</Function>
    <Unit>Volume (1e-1  m^3)</Unit>
    <Value>0</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
<DataRecord id="14">
    <Function>Manufacturer specific</Function>
    <Value>00 00</Value>
    <Timestamp>2018-02-02T20:43:39</Timestamp>
</DataRecord>
</MBusData>
```

PS: As far as I could go, I am stucked on:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.fromString
```

So, is the sring passed as parameter (my XML string above) too long?
Do I have a way to *paused* the script, so this function has enough time to finish?

Comment: so it freezes and give no error output?

Comment: Actually, I am debugging the task with *logging* module, and the traces stops at the very beginning of this pw3_parseDOM. I don't know how to redirect error stream to logging trace. It could be helpfull though.

Comment: I finally found the solution. As in many post about _cron_ , the problem came from the external command I launched with _POpen_, the command did not contain the absolute path of the script. Sorry, and thanks for watching this